# Ruby Enterprise Edition vs. Matz' Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently written a little website + CMS in Rails in order to learn Ruby. I was a little surprised to see Rails' memory use which feels a lot - but to be honest I never really looked at the memory use of my Django apps.

Now, most people recommend Ruby Enterprise Edition in order to lower the memory footprint of your Rails apps. However, I was wondering why there isn't an official Ubuntu package. Does REE have an incompatible license, or is there anything else funny about it? Ubuntu has pretty much a package for everything, why is it hesitant to embrace REE?

Also, are there any tradeoffs of REE vs. Matz' Ruby?

Comment: http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/comparisons.html

Comment: Wow, those comparisons are comparing ruby 1.8.6 with ruby EE. I've been looking at other similar Stack Overflow threads that assert that Ruby 1.9 has many of the EE improvements.

Comment: Lenni, you should look into Ruby Version Manager - http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: I'd prefer to do everything with apt-get - even if that means writing my own package.

Answer (score 1):

Ree is a fork of Ruby unofficial. All is weel explain on their FAQ why there are difference and why it's not merge on ruby official. Ubuntu can have some package of ree, but noone create it in official ubuntu repository

http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

REE is fully compatible with MRI counterpart (Matz's). One caveat though is that REE is slow in merging changes from MRI upstream. And worry not, at the time of this writing, REE has merged all changes from MRI 1.8.7-p334. Enjoy!

I'd love to see someone tackle REE Debian Package creation. If you think you got what it takes, why don't you give packaging a try?

I had few servers running REE with Passenger Phusion and they are very robust and stable (never crash on me). So it should answer your question if it acts up funny or not.